# Isomorphism between tangentspace of Lie group quotient and quotient of Lie algebras.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, principal-bundles

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup with Lie algebras $\mathfrak g, \mathfrak h$. Then the canonical projection $p: G \to G/H$ is a submersion.
Fix a $g \in G$. 
We have a linear isomorphism $\omega(g): T_g G \to \mathfrak g$ given by the Maurer-Cartan form $\omega$, i.e. $\omega(g)(X) = T_g \lambda_{g^{-1}}$ ($\lambda_g$ left multiplication with $g$). Further we have the projection $\pi: \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$.

I want to show that we have a linear isomorphism $\varphi_g: T_{gH}(G/H)\to \mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$. To define it, I want to define $\varphi_g$ such that $\varphi_g \circ T_g p = \pi \circ \omega(g)$.
For this to be well-defined (and injective) I should make clear to myself why $\ker T_g p = \omega^{-1}(\mathfrak h)$. Did I get this right?
($\omega^{-1}(g) = T_e \lambda_g$, right?)

I've read somewhere this line:
$\ker T_e p = T_e(p^{-1}(eH)) = T_e H = \mathfrak h$, i.e. the kernel of $T_e p$ is the tangent space at $e$ of the fiber $p^{-1}(eH)$. Why is that?
And how to continue the calculation $\ker T_g p = T_g(gH)$? That is, why is
$T_g(gH) = T_e \lambda_g (\mathfrak h) (=\omega^{-1}(\mathfrak h))?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general result you should be familiar with. Let $f \colon M \rightarrow N$ be a smooth map and let $q \in N$ be a regular value of $f$. Then $f^{-1}(q)$ is a smooth submanifold of $M$ and if $p \in f^{-1}(q)$ then $T_p(f^{-1}(q)) = \ker df_p$. To see this, note that if $\gamma \colon I \rightarrow f^{-1}(q)$ is a smooth curve with $\gamma(0) = p$ then

$$ df_p(\dot{\gamma}(0)) = \frac{d}{dt} f(\gamma(t))|_{t = 0} = \frac{d}{dt} q|_{t = 0} = 0. $$

This shows that $T_p(f^{-1}(q)) \subseteq \ker df_p$ and since the dimensions of the two vector spaces are equal, we must have equality.

In your case, $p$ is a submersion so any value is a regular value and you have 
$$T_g(gH) = T_g(p^{-1}(gH)) = \ker dp_{g}. $$

Comment: Thank you! Just one question: why in the end we have $T_g(gH) = T_e \lambda_g(\mathfrak h)$? (or did I get sth wrong above?)

Comment: That has nothing to do with what you asked. The subgroup $H$ is a embedded submanifold of $G$ and under the obvious identifications, we have $T_e(H) = \mathfrak{h} \subseteq \mathfrak{g} = T_e(G)$. The submanifold $gH$ is simply the image of $H$ under the diffeomorphism $\lambda_g$ and so $d\lambda_g|_e \colon T_e(G) \rightarrow T_g(G)$ maps the tangent space of $H$ at $e$ to the tangent space of $\lambda_g(H) = gH$ at $\lambda_g(e) = g$. Thus, $T_g(gH) = d\lambda_g|_e(\mathfrak{h})$.